# how to output ucs2_unicode data with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-16

I am stuck on a project that requires foreign language characters.
I need to input these and store them in the database as well as output them from the database to the screen.

For example, I have this string `Kupon obuhvaća:` that shows as `Kupon obuhvaÄ‡a:` when I output it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You will need to show some code, database table definitions, database connection and charset setup, and HTML page headers (`<meta charset=`).

Comment: If your database is collated in utf-8 and the html encoding is utf-8 it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry turns out it was because of my framework (codeigniter) which was set to utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, turns out it was because my framework (codeigniter) was set to utf-8 . Hate it when I find the answer RIGHT after posting a question (*embarrassed* )